# Which version of the Selenium firefox web driver is recommended?

Tags: r, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Apologies if I've gotten the terminology wrong. I'm following the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/basics.html) on R selenium to the letter, and so I'm using version 2.53.1 of the standalone firefox web driver in docker:

```
docker run -d -p 5901:5900 -p 127.0.0.1:4445:4444 --link http-server selenium/standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1
```

I'm playing around trying to fetch my student data automatically from my university, and so far I've managed to choose the correct university from a list, logging in with my username/password and clicking the "my education" button. Here I get stuck. It doesn't matter if I click the link in the debug tool (that would be tightVNC Viewer) or if I tell the script which links should be clicked. I end up with an empty page with just the word "filter" on it:

[image]

This doesn't seem to happen when I use regular firefox:

[image]

Also, for some reason the first page is in English why the second is not.

Since the issue remains the same regardless if I use commands or the debug tool the issue might be the web driver I think. Should I still be using version 2.53.1 or is there a newer, better version out there?

Which one in that case?

If I'm on the wrong track and the problem is something else entirely then please tell me so!

Comment: Which driver are you using? The latest for firefox is GeckoDriver v 29

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with mismatched driver versions. If that were the case, typically the browser would launch (if at all) and not be issued any commands afterwards. It sounds like you might be clicking the wrong link. Also, your FF instance may be detected as English where your personal browser is being detected as your native language.

Comment: @C.Peck I'm following the instructions in the vignette in to the letter. It just tells me to use standalone-firefox-debug:2.53.1. I can't really tell what that package contains (so what version of firefox is used and with what driver).

Comment: @JeffC

I don't know, I clicked the exact same link in the debug tool and in my personal browser, even the url is exacly the same :/

Comment: OK... I would investigate the browser being detected as English. Is there a setting in the FF driver where you can indicate a native language? Are you running this script on a box where the UI is English? etc. For debugging purposes... have you tried adding a 3s wait before clicking the link that's giving you issues? Maybe the page isn't fully loaded and it's clicking a malformed URL.

Comment: @JeffC

Adding 3 sec didn't seem to help much

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with the Docker instance. I don't do Docker. Can you put a breakpoint on your test, launch it, and then manually take over and try to click links? If not, I think the solution is still where is the browser detecting English... maybe from the Docker instance?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm totally new at this, What is a breakpoint? I won't require a lengthy explanation, just a link to a tutorial or something would be fine :)

Comment: I just ran across this... maybe this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67423676/whats-the-right-way-to-pass-browser-profile-to-selenium-inside-docker-container